# C++ text file editor crashes on file edit

Tags: c++, file, runtime-error, ofstream

Let me preface by saying I'm very new to C++, coming from Java and wanting to learn new languages.

I used ofstream to write an array to a text file, by looping through the array, as seen below.

When I go to open the file in Notepad++ or Microsoft's notepad, I see all the entries in the file, however there is a runtime error that crashes the editor.

My main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    //Prototyped functions
    int getMenuOption();
    int printMenu();
    void beginNewVocabularySet();

    void printIntro();

    int option = getMenuOption();

    switch(option){

    case 2: beginNewVocabularySet();

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The function that calls the function below

```
void beginNewVocabularySet(){

    int vocabSize = 0;

    cout << "Please enter the length of the vocabulary set\n";

    cin >> vocabSize;

    string vocabArray[vocabSize];

    cout << "Please enter a word, then press enter to make the second entry.\n";

    for(int i=0; i < vocabSize; i++){

         cin >> vocabArray[i];
         cout << "Entry number " << i+1 << ". " << vocabArray[i] << "\n";

    }

    saveVocabSet(vocabArray, vocabSize);


}
```

The function that writes the array to the file

```
int saveVocabSet(string vocabArr[], int arrSize){

    ofstream vocabFile ("vocabList.txt");

    if (vocabFile.is_open()){

        for(int i=0; i<=arrSize; i++){

            vocabFile<< vocabArr[i] << "\n";

        }

        vocabFile.close();

    }else {

        cout << "Unable to open file";
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The text editor itself crashes? Both of them? That is very strange.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<=arrSize; i++){` Are you sure about the `<=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `saveVocabSet` you're accessing array out of bound

```
for(int i=0; i <= arrSize; i++)
//             ~~ should be i < arrSize or i <= arrSize-1
```

Array indices should go from 0 to `arrSize`-1

Comment: That did it! Not sure why that would cause a runtime error in notepad, unless the terminated program still had the file open, since it never left the loop.

Thanks, I'll accept the answer once stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: @AhellHound: Best to delete it, since it was a simple typo. This isn't going to help anyone else.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Won't let me delete it. I'll flag for a moderator.